# Slim 3 & Stripe API compatibility issues

Tags: php, apache, stripe-payments, slim

I started a web application using Slim 3. I went to add in the Stripe API and got a Slim Application error message. I removed the Stripe API code, and the error went away.

```
// Setup
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('xx_test_XXXXxXxXXXXXxXxXXxXXXxXX');

// Get Token
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Charge the user's card:
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 1000,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "description" => "Example charge",
  "source" => $token,
```

));

I've Googled a few things, but still haven't found the source of the problem. I suspect that the `\Stripe\` is the culprit, but I don't know why it is.

Comment: What's the error that you got? Slim shouldn't just throw an application error, you should be able to get an output of what the issue is

Comment: Hmm, is there something I have to do in order to set that up? All I have is "Slim Application Error" title with "A website error has occurred. Sorry for the temporary inconvenience." below.

Comment: Did it, it says "Class 'Stripe' not found."

Comment: Are you including the Stripe PHP library?  https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#composer

Comment: I am including the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a blank error page from Slim Framework you can find out the actual error in two ways:

1. Check your PHP `error_log` as Slim will write the error there.
2. Update your `settings` to set `displayErrorDetails` to `true`.
   i.e.

   ```
   $config = [
       'settings' => [
           'displayErrorDetails' => true, // set to false in production
           'addContentLengthHeader' => false, // Allow the web server to send the content-length header

       ],
   ];
   $app = new \Slim\App($config);
   ```

   The error message page will now display the details about what is actually wrong.

Hopefully, you'll then be able to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I found the error. It turns out that it was a simple loading issue (I ran the app before loading the proper resource) - After that, it was just your everyday troubleshooting.